# C++ storing callbacks with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, callback

I really need your help. As I'm a beginner I got stuck at storing callbacks with variadic arguments.

The goal is, to store x callbacks with their n arguments of type y. I tried with templates, but stucked at their deduction. The callbacks need be triggered later in my existing static library by other events changing the callbacks arguments. All callback functions always will/have to return void.

In my main.cpp I need to have:

```
void testFunc_i(int i){
    //do something
}
void subscribe_i(){
    myLib::registerCallback(
        "something", "INT",
        &testFunc_i
    );
}

void testFunc_ivf(int i, std::vector<float> f){
    //do something
}
void subscribe_ivf(){
    myLib::registerCallback(
        "another string",   "INT",
        "something different",  "FLOAT[]",
        &testFunc_ivf
    );
}
void testFunc_ifs(int i, float f, std::string s){
    //do something
}
void subscribe_ifs(){
    myLib::registerCallback(
        "foo",  "INT",
        "bar",  "FLOAT",
        "text", "STRING",
        &testFunc_ifs
    );
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    subscribe_i();
    subscribe_ivf();
    subscribe_ifs();
}
```

What I do have in myLib is something like:

```
namespace myLib{

    class Subscriber
    {
    public:
        Subscriber();
        ~Subscriber();
        void addString(const std::string &s)
        {
            v.push_back(s);
        }
        void addType(const std::string &s)
        {
            t.push_back(s);
        }
        void setCallback(callback_t callbackFn) //???
        {
            callback = callbackFn; // ???
        }

        void call( /* ??? */ )
        {
            // ???
            callback(); // ???
        }
    private:
        callback_t callback; // ???

        std::vector<std::strings>v;
        std::vector<std::strings>t;
    };

    // if argument is a string
    void add(unsigned &cnt, auto* subscriber, const std::string &value)
    {
        if (cnt%2==0) {
            subscriber->addString(value);
        }else{
            subscriber->addType(value);
        }
        cnt++;
    }

    // if argument is a function
    template <typename... Args>
    void add(unsigned &cnt, auto* subscriber, void(*_callbackFn)(Args...) )
    {
        subscriber->setCallback(_callbackFn);
    }

    template <typename... Ts>
    void registerCallback(Ts&&... ts)
    {
        auto subscriber = new Subscriber();
        unsigned cnt = 0;
        auto dummy = {(add(cnt,subscriber,ts), 0)...};
        Store::getInstance().addSubsriber(subscriber); //store the subscriber object in a Singleton (working)
    }
}
```

Comment: are the parameters to be passed known when registering the callback or later? If it is the first, the solution is to have callbacks that take no parameters

Comment: the parameter type is known when registering, its value later or never. I need to be able to change variables of the main.cpp from inside the library, so no parameter is no option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that this way.

If you are using variadic arguments in a function, the best you can do is convert these arguments in a tuple.

However, one tuple is different to any other tuple with any different argument list, so you can't store that in a container for calling back later.

If tuples were to derive from a common base class, you'd be able to store them until use (that has to go through a layer of double dispatch with a `virtual call()` method). That's not very convenient to write since it implies almost rewriting the `std::tuple` type.

If I were you, I would do the opposite instead, that is, make a lambda that's calling the callback as passed, and store it converted to a `std::function` in a container for later calling.

Something along this pseudo code (not tested):

```
   template <typename F, typename... Args>
   void registerCallback(F f, Args&&... args)
   {
      // Make a function that's calling the callback and store that instead
      std::function<void()> laterCB = [&] { f(args...); };
      // Simply store in your std::vector<std::function<void()>> container
      Store::getInstance().addSubscriber(laterCB);
   }

   void triggerCB()
   {
       for (auto i : Store::getInstance().getCB()) 
           *i();
   }
```

*Another remark:*

This kind of code is always very unsafe because the arguments' type can be references (there is nothing in the syntax that could prevent that). When called back later, the referenced object might not exist anymore.
If you have to write a library, you'd be better to avoid doing this and instead make your interface very rigid to prevent this.

Example unsafe use:

```
// DON'T DO THAT
struct A { ... };
int processA(A & a) { 
  a.foo();
}

if (something())
{
   A a;
   yourLib.registerCallback(processA, a);
}

// Calls processA with a reference on a 
// destructed object 'a' => so it'll crash
yourLib.triggerCB();
```

Comment: it isnt quite true that it is not possible. Type erasure is possible, its just not simple.

Comment: You're right. I've edited my post. But for a beginner, it's almost impossible to get right.

Comment: well thanks for you fast answer. Unfortunately it don't really see where you pass the new values as arguments when calling the callback. I guess the code strongly depends on this.  
Almost impossible is still an option. I really like to give it a try ;) Every suggestion is welcome. (I already had a working solution in a not so type save programming language.By saying I'm a beginner, I just meant I'm new into c++ and its concepts)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it.

Hope it helps :- ) ('m using Qt, feel free to replace the qt container with std)

```cpp
class CallbackLambda {

public:
    template<typename F>
    void store_lambda(const QString &key, F &&f) {
        using arg_tuple = typename function_traits<F>::arg_tuple;
        using return_type = typename function_traits<F>::return_type;

        myHash[key] = [f = std::forward<F>(f)](std::any args) -> std::any {
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<return_type, void>) {
                std::apply(f, std::any_cast<arg_tuple &>(args));
                return {};
            } else {
                return std::apply(f, std::any_cast<arg_tuple &>(args));
            }
        };
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    std::any call(const QString &key, Args... arg) {
        return call_lambda(myHash[key], arg...);
    }
private:
    QHash<QString, std::function<std::any(std::any)>> myHash;

    template<typename T>
    struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {
    };

    template<typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const> {
        using arg_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
        using return_type = ReturnType;
    };

    template<typename... Args>
    std::any call_lambda(const std::function<std::any(std::any)> &f, Args &&... args) {
        return f(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

};

int main() {
    auto manager = CallbackLambda();
    manager.store_lambda("print", []() {
        std::cout << "Hello, world!\n" << std::endl;
    });

    manager.store_lambda("int", [](int x, int y)  {
        std::cout << "The sum of " << x << " and " << y << " is " << (x + y) << std::endl;
        return x + y;
    });

    manager.store_lambda("float", [](float val, float v) {
        std::cout << "Message: " << val << " " << v << std::endl;
    });


    manager.store_lambda("stdString", [](std::string message) {
        std::cout << "Message: " << message << "\n" << std::endl;
    });
    manager.store_lambda("qString", [](QString message) {
        std::cout << "Message: " << message.toStdString() << "\n" << std::endl;
    });
    manager.store_lambda("char", [](const char *message) {
        std::cout << "Message: " << message << "\n" << std::endl;
    });
    manager.store_lambda("double", [](double val, double v) {
        std::cout << "Message: " << val << " " << v << std::endl;
    });

    manager.call("print");
    auto out = manager.call("int", 10, 20);
    std::cout << std::any_cast<int>(out) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Happy callbacking.

You probably want to edit `call` to check if callback exists else return nullptr or something like that...

[C++ storing callbacks with variadic arguments and getting return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76141684/c-storing-callbacks-with-variadic-arguments-and-getting-return/76141685#76141685)

Comment: I just tried that it works perfectly ! But I can't really wrap my head around it. If you have any links / details about the pattern you used that could help the general understanding of this snippet it would be great